# Wordpress Robots.txt does /feed matter?

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a question questions regarding SEO, Robots.txt and wordpress

Here's what my robots.txt looks like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-includes
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: /*/feed
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /tag
Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /archive/
Disallow: /rss/
Disallow: /about/trackback/
Disallow: /wp-register.php
```

In Google Webmasters tools I see urls like this being restricted:

http://www.domain.com/date/article-title/feed/

Which is because of the Disallow /feed I assume, now the real article title is the same url with out the '/feed/'
http://www.domain.com/date/article-title/

My question is will the right URL still get indexed by Search Engines? Or should I remove it from the robots.txt? And what do you think of the robots.txt I did some searching on found tips of what to add in and came out with that, but when I look at hte bigger wordpress sites they don't have half the items I have in my robots txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed itself won't get indexed but the URLs contained within it can be indexed if their URLs are not specifically blocked in the robots.txt file.

As long as all of your blog articles are indexed the other stuff can be blocked without issue.  It looks like some of the blocked pages are useless to users and search engines (i.e. login pages, trackback pages) or potentially duplicate content issues (i.e. archives, tag pages). The useless pages should be blocked outright. I would let the archive and tag pages be crawled but not indexed. That way search engines can follow the links on those pages which will help them find all of your content. This wouldn't be done with a robots.txt but either a [meta tag or HTTP header](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html).

Comment: Okay so the post URL will be fine since they don't have /feed? And I will add those meta tags, here's a link to the actually robots.txt www.mugenbits.com/robots.txt